Air Canada: eTA & Online check-in
This is my first question in this community, thank for reading.
I have my flight in 24 hours with Air Canada, and I was trying to do the online check-in, however when I reached the point when I am asked about the 2nd travel document, I chose eTA then clicked on Save, then I got the error as shown in the red rectangle.

I have my eTA and confirmed its validity for 4 years from now.
There is no section on the Air Canada website to enter my eTA information.
I travelled once before to Canada and I remember doing the online checking in with no problem.
I called the customer services and they told me that an agent at the airport will help regarding this issue. This is a little bit frustrating to be honest because I am concered if there's anything wrong.

Has anyone been in this similar situation before? I appreciate your comments and thoughts.


They use your name, passport number and date of birth to verify the status of your eTA (and against other lists). Check if those are supplied correctly and exactly the same as your primary travel document. But technical errors happen quite often with online check-in interfaces and you may have to see a ground agent for help.

did you book through AirCanada or through an agent/partner airline? did you provide your ETA then?

Did you complete your API data before trying to check in online?

@meego I booked directly through AirCanada, and yes as I remember I provided my ETA otherwise I wouldn't be able to complete the booking I think.

@Traveller Excuse me, but what is API data?!

@xngtng I think I entered all the information correctly and they are matched with the ones on eTA. Just in case I had a mistake somewhere, where can I find that? And can I modify them by myself or should be done by the agent?

@philippos can you see if you can verify the ETA data you provided by going to the manage booking section (not check-in), valide data and update it if there was a typo.
https://www.aircanada.com/home/nl/en/aco/trips

@meego I checked that page, it's not showing that I provided any eTA data, nor showing an option to add one.

In that info-box at the bottom, there seems to be a link to an official eTA-Website where you can check your status. That would at least help with your unease about anything being wrong with your eTA.

@Sabine I already checked the status of eTA and it's still valid.

I don’t understand your point 4.  You claim to have all the documents so what can go wrong?  Plus, if something does go wrong, you have basically very limited between checkin and flight to fix it.

Have you checked for any typos like I/1 (letter i/digit one) or O/0 (letter o/digit 0) in your input (both in the ETA application and the airline check-in)?
